# GCloud instances list is not refreshed after compute manage group resource is created, count.index is set of string with 1 element

Tags: terraform, devops, gcloud

I apologize for the inconvenience in this group, but I have a slight issue. I'm trying to retrieve the IPs once I provision a cluster of VMs in Google Cloud. After the creation of the 'google_compute_instance_group_manager' resource, I attempt to retrieve the number of instances created using a count through datasources. However, I encounter an error:

```
│ │ count.index is 1 │ │ data.google_compute_instance_group.mig.instances is set of string with 1 element
```

I have tried various approaches to resolve this issue, and the latest one seemed to be the best by using a script and waiting for the number of instances returned to match the cluster_size. Do you have any ideas about what might be happening? The script is working, it returns the number of instances I'm expecting, but the when it's going to the  datasource '"google_compute_instance" "instance_in_mig',  it's thowing the error I mentioned before, if I run apply again, it works.
I would like to make it work without having to run it twice because aftwards I need to create and setup a bastion host (with iap tunneling) to configure the internal ip addresses of my cluster. so I can configure them through ansible

I would appreciate your help in advance

This is my code:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "nginx_group" {
  name               = "nginx-group"
  base_instance_name = var.instance_template_name
  zone               = var.zone
  target_size        = var.cluster_size

  version {
    instance_template = var.instance_template
  }

   target_pools       = [google_compute_target_pool.nginx_pool.self_link]

}

data "google_compute_instance_group" "mig" {
  name = "nginx-group"
  zone = var.zone
  depends_on = [ google_compute_instance_group_manager.nginx_group  ]
}

resource "null_resource" "wait_for_instances" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "while [ $(gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances nginx-group | grep \"RUNNING\" | wc -l) -lt ${var.cluster_size} ]; do sleep 5; done; sleep 10"
  }

  depends_on = [ data.google_compute_instance_group.mig ]
}

data "google_compute_instance" "instance_in_mig" {

  count = var.cluster_size
  self_link = tolist(data.google_compute_instance_group.mig.instances)[count.index]

  depends_on = [  null_resource.wait_for_instances ]
}
```

Comment: The existence of Compute Engine instances is managed by the MIG and not by Terraform. Even if you wait for instances to be created to fetch each IP address, the instance might then be terminated. Depending on how IP addresses are assigned to each instance, you might be using an IP address that is later assigned to a new instance.

Comment: so, how can I get the ip addresses, do I have to create a pool of ips before?, I'm currently creating ephemeral ip addresses so I can test my provisioning with ansible but I need the addresss to be right because I need to provision a bastion host using their internal ip addresses, I can run apply twice but I think is not the best approach

Comment: Often it is useful if you clearly specify the goal (problem to solve). In your case use a subnet for the instances and allow any instance in that subnet.

Comment: Also, I think you misunderstand what a Managed Instance Group is/does. I think you might want to review Unmanaged Instance Group if you want fixed instances that you control.

Comment: thank you @JohnHanley you're right maybe I should have used unmanaged group, however I already solved it by following a slightly different approach, I generated a file based on the information returned by 'gcloud compute instance list' and then read this file and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Did you think about how you will handle changes? MIGs create and terminate instances. What you see now might be very different in a few hours.

Comment: you're right, I will try to do the unmanged group or maybe create an image and then let the mig handle the instances using this image?  

anyway what was trying to do was just a quick provisioning for a showcase (non production ready)

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it by doing this instead:

*modules/ipfetcher.tf*

```
resource "time_sleep" "wait_for_instances_creation" {
  create_duration = var.wait_for_instances
}

resource "random_string" "suffix" {
  length  = 5
  special = false
}

locals {
  filename = "instance_ips_${random_string.suffix.result}.out"
}

resource "null_resource" "get_instance_ips" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./fetch_instances.sh ${var.cluster_size} ${local.filename}"
  }

  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_for_instances_creation]
}


output "external_ips" {
  value = split("\n", chomp(file("./${local.filename}")))

  depends_on = [ null_resource.get_instance_ips ]
}
```

*fetch_instances.sh*

```bash
size=$1
filename=$2

while [ $(gcloud compute instances list | grep 'RUNNING' | wc -l) -lt ${size} ] 
do 
    sleep 5; 
done;
gcloud compute instances list | grep 'RUNNING' | awk '{print $5}' > ./$2
```

I had to create a file using the gcloud CLI to obtain the IP addresses (currently external ips) in order to use these addresses later with **Ansible**. I had to generate the file name using random strings to ensure it always gets refreshed.

Thank you to John Hanley for your responses.